# Null reference in my script in UNITY3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

Hi guys im kinda new with unity c# scripting. Im getting an null reference exception in my code. Here is my code:

```
public class LoginUI : InputAwareWindow
{
  [Inject]
   Private AccountManager _xAccount_Manager;

   void Start ()
   {
     Username.text = _xaccount_manager.GetLastUsername();
     Password.text = _xaccount_manager.GetLastPassword();

     if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(Error.text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username.text) )
     {
        Error.text = HelpText;
     }
   }

    void OnLogin()
    {
      if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username.text) )
      {     
       _xaccount_manager.Login(Username.text, Password.text); <- error here

       NGUITools.SetActive(MyWaitUI, true);
      }
      else
      {
        Error.text = HelpText;
      }
    }
}

 public class AccountManager:Basebehavior
 {
   public void Login(string username, string password)
   {
    _username = username;
    _password = password;

    Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    data["username"] = username;
    data["password"] = password;

    _server_link.Request("login", OnLoginResult, data);
   }
 }
```

I already set all the fields in the hierarchy window where the script is attached to but still gets the error. Thank you. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Where the exception is raised?

Comment: in the onlogin(). The code  _xaccount_manager.Login(Username.text, Password.text). Sorry for the confusion. The public void login is in the Class _xaccount_manager

Comment: So one of this has to be null: _xaccount_manager, Username, Password. Username is unlikely - exception would be raised earlier. Debug your code in IDE or write above 3xDebug.Log(...) with that objects and determine which one is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Class object _xaccount_manager is null

you have to instantiate your object like following be in start method our where ever you want to but before  calling your onlogin method

_xaccount_manager = new AccountManager ();